# Reading Gmail Email in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, gmail, imap

I am attempting to create a simple script to check my Gmail for emails with a certain title. When I run this program on Python 3.7.3 I receive this data: `('OK', [b'17'])`.

I need to access the body of the email within python. I am just not sure what to do with the data that I have.

Here is my current code:

```
import imaplib
import credentials

imap_ssl_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
imap_ssl_port = 993
username = credentials.email
password = credentials.passwd
server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_ssl_host, imap_ssl_port)

server.login(username, password)
server.select('INBOX')

data = server.uid('search',None, '(SUBJECT "MY QUERY HERE!")')
print(data)
```

The result from running the code:

```
('OK', [b'17'])
```

I know it is a little rough, but I am still learning, so any advice you have to help me improve would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't the API be better in the long run?  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first list the contents of the selected mailbox and fetch one of the items. You could do something like this (also check the link suggested by @asynts)

```
    imap.select('Inbox')
    status, data = imap.search(None, 'ALL')
    for num in data[0].split():
      status, data = imap.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
      email_msg = data[0][1]
```

If you only want specific fields in the body, instead of parsing the RFC you could filter fields like:

```
    status, data = imap.fetch(num, '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT DATE FROM TO)])')
```

Comment: That worked! Now I can run "print(email_msg)" at the end of my program, and it gives me the information in the header of my email. 

I have two questions though.

Is there any way that I can access the body of the email?

Is there a list of commands that I can reference for the "imap.fetch" function?
When I say a list of commands I mean how did you know what to put in the parentheses of the "imap.fetch()" function?
Sorry for my ignorance. I am still learning. Thank you for your help!

Comment: imaplib is a low level library.  You'll need to understand a lot more (eg, RFC 3501) to know what to put.  Alternatively you can try something higher level.  I've heard people use imapclient here; or use gmail's HTTP apis, which are probably easier to understand

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Max. If I want to find the body specifically instead of the header would you suggest I look in the gmail HTTP apis?

Comment: user.message has a body field in HTTP.  I've not used it myself.  But the guides and documentations have built in HTTP "Try It" buttons for experimenting.  You could start here, https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get or go back and read some overview guides.